# Interpreting zero locus in 3 variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem I'm working on is as follows:

"Let $Y = Z(x^2-yz,xz-x) \subset \mathbb{A}^3$. Show that $Y$ is the union of three irreducible components and describe them and their prime ideals."

I believe I have the first part down, i.e. $Y = Z_1 \cup Z_2 \cup Z_3$ where $Z_1 = Z(x^2-y,z-1)$, $Z_2 = Z(x,y)$ and $Z_3 = Z(x,z)$.

Now I'm trying to describe the zero loci. The latter two are somewhat obvious -- just the $z$-axis and the $y$-axis respectively, but the first is starting to give me a headache.

I think we can interpret $Z_1$ as the intersection of the quadratic surface $x^2-y$ with the plane $z=1$, but I'm not entirely sure. Any advice on visualizing these kinds of things?

(For the record, this is a homework question, and the professor is very specific about not using techniques from outside his notes to solve things. We haven't done anything with projective varieties yet, just affine varieties, so if you can please avoid those kinds of answers.)

Comment: Yes, your interpretation of $Z_1$ is correct.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you. I'm now going to try to go above and beyond and draw this thing in 3D using PGFplots, which is a little daunting. Usually these things are easier if you use parametric equations, but I can't quite remember how to go about that.

Comment: For reference, this is Ex. I.1.3 in Hartshorne. I'm sure it's been asked here a bunch of times, so you could probably read an unreasonable amount of words it.

Comment: @Hoot My professor has compiled his own notes about the subject and we are working from those, so I wasn't aware this was from Hartshorne, but I will examine solutions from there. From seeing earlier solutions out of Hartshorne, they tend to involve more sophisticated machinery than we have access to in the course, since as I noted the professor is pretty specific about just using material from his notes and not using outside works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In search of understanding about this particular zero locus, I decided to tinker with PGFplots to get a nice visualization of what's going on.

[image]

The red, blue, and green portions are the actual irreducible elements of the zero locus, the rest is showing the plane cutting the parabolic sheet.

Thanks to TeX StackExchange user @Lorehead for helping me get this fixed up.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to recognize is that the algebra you did already contains all the geometry of the question! Let's look at how to work out these irreducible components, and see that it's really completely geometric.

Your variety $Y$ is the intersection of two equations in three variables. The first is irreducible, and defines the quadric surface $x^2 = yz$. Let's try to visualize this (using real coordinates to avoid thinking about six real dimensions!). The first idea we might have is to look at level surfaces: if we let $x$ range over the real numbers, we see that we have a family of curves $yz = t$, where $t$ is a positive number. For $t \neq 0$, this is a hyperbola, and for $t = 0$ it's a pair of intersecting lines. Maybe this hints at what our surface is, but it's certainly not entirely obvious from here. Taking level curves in $y$ and $z$ is similarly unhelpful.

So let's change the coordinates and see if we can make it easier. Let $s = \frac{1}{2}(y + z)$ and $t = \frac{1}{2}(y - z)$ (basically rotating by $45$ degrees, but with a scale factor as well). Then the equation $x^2 = yz$ becomes $x^2 =  (s + t) (s - t) = (s^2 - t^2)$. Thus, our equation can be written $x^2 + t^2 = s^2$. This suggests taking level curves in $s$. For $s = 0$, we get $x^2 + t^2 = 0$; this is just the point $(0,0)$ (in real coordinates, of course). Now notice that the equation is symmetric about $s = 0$, and for $s \neq 0$, we get the equation $x^2 + t^2 = s^2$, a circle with radius $s$. Thus, we can see that our surface is a circular cone opening along the $s$-axis.

Ok, so much for the first equation. The second one is easier: it factors as $x(z-1)$, so it's the union of the two planes $x = 0$ and $z = 1$. Now, let's intersect each plane with our cone.

The intersection of $x = 0$ with the cone $x^2 = yz$ is clearly the union of the lines $x = y = 0$ and $x = z = 0$. The intersection of $z = 1$ with the cone is the parabola $x^2 = y$, contained in the $z = 1$ plane. Thus, our variety is the union of three irreducible components: two intersecting lines in the $x = 0$ plane and a parabola in the $z = 1$ plane. We see that the line $x = y = 0$ connects the line $x = z = 0$ to the vertex of the parabola.